# How do you add a PDF attachment to a page?

Tags: files, 9

Complete Drupal Newbie here.  I have created a basic Drupal 9 site so as to teach myself Drupal.  I have added some Basic pages, and put them onto the menu.  I can edit the text in each page just fine, however there are two things that I can't figure out how to do.

I want to add downloadable PDF attachments to some of the pages.

I also want to add pictures to my page. I'm not sure how either of these things are done.  There does not appear to be any obvious option for uploading files.

I have looked at: https://www.drupal.org/node/347251 - but this page appears to be about creating Drupal forms that would [then] be able to upload files.  But what I want to do is - in edit mode, add PDF attachments to my pages that can then be downloaded by a person viewing that page.

Similarly, I want to be able to upload images that can then be displayed in the HTML page.

Is this something that is doable out of the box, or do you need a plugin/module of some kind?

Comment: In the content type page add a new **file field**. Editors are then able when creating or editing a page to upload files there. In the display settings for this content type you then can choose how this file will be displayed. Same for images. Simply add an **image field**.

If your site gonna be content-, file- and image-heavy consider using the Media module instead and then add multiple **media fields**, each allowing a different **media type** to be attached. Media gives you the option to easily reuse certain media on multiple places and choose from a media library.

Comment: great, that's got it.  Thanks heaps :-)